# Как сделать сортировку картинок из MySQL?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, backend

Всем привет.

Хочу сделать простейшую страницу для перебора фото в базе данных (для наглядности).

Выглядит так:
1. На страницу выводится фото (url берется из базы)
2. 2 кнопки - ок/не ок. При нажатии на одну - в столбец писать тру, на другую - фолс.
3. После нажатия на кнопку берется следующая строка из базы, соответственно выводится следующая картинка.

И так до конца.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чего начать.

Вроде циклом как-то, а вроде и нет. Вроде и без JS можно, а может лучше и с ним.

Подскажите, как бы вы делали?

Comment: начать с того, чтобы определиться каким способом собираетесь делать. как вы правильно отметили, можно обойтись и без js. а если с js то можно и по одной картинке загружать, а можно список сразу получить, и использовать "цикл" для листания картинок

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не знаете JS, то либо учите и делайте с ним, либо без него. Опишу самый простой вариант.
Делаете запрос в базу вида

```
SELECT `id`, `link` FROM `image` WHERE `viewed` != 'true' LIMIT 1
```

Проверяете кол-во записей в ответе. Если больше 0, то
Выводите на страницу саму картинку. И две кнопки ссылки, в которых передаете id картинки и свойство тру или фолс, все это ведет на какой-то файл обработчик.
Там проверяете что пришло тру или фолс и обновляете соответствующее значение у картинки с тем id, который передали + ставите viewed = true.
После этого возвращаетесь на страницу с картинками, загружается уже новая и т.д. Без цикла все будет.
Делаете, пока не вернется 0 записей с бд и тогда можно вывести типа "Картинок больше нет".

Очень простой вариант и небезопасный, если дополнительно никаких проверок не делать и т.п.